# Permutations on elements a>b && b>c

Tags: combinatorics, permutation

```
A={1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
Permutations[A, {3}]
```

I need to print all permutations where the first number is bigger than the 
second and the second number is bigger than the third:

lets say (5,4,3), ...(5,3,1), ...(4,2,1)...(3,2,1).
it needs to be done with **A={1, 2, 3, 4, 5}**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Select[Permutations[A, {3}], Greater @@ # &]
```

Comment: just perfect! thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 11):

```
Subsets[Reverse@Range[5], {3}]
```

> {{5, 4, 3}, {5, 4, 2}, {5, 4, 1}, {5, 3, 2}, {5, 3, 1}, {5, 2, 1},
>           {4, 3, 2}, {4, 3, 1}, {4, 2, 1}, {3, 2, 1}}

```
Reverse /@ Subsets[Range[5], {3}]
```

> {{3, 2, 1}, {4, 2, 1}, {5, 2, 1}, {4, 3, 1}, {5, 3, 1}, {5, 4, 1}, 
>           {4, 3, 2}, {5, 3, 2}, {5, 4, 2}, {5, 4, 3}}

Comment: I took a quick look at execution times for the three proposed solutions, just for fun. Mine below and @Algohi's are roughly equivalent, but yours blows us both clean out of the water! It makes sense considering that you are doing no pattern matching etc, but it's still pretty impressive! Thanks for posting this! (+1)

Comment: @MarcoB, thank you for the upvote.  There are a  whole lot more `Permutations` than  `Subsets` (which leads to about 10x increase in `Timing`  for `Range[200]` even without the selection part). Then, you need to process this huge set to find the right  elements --  which, in turn,  takes ~10x the time it takes to construct the `Permutations`.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding a little on the OP's problem, here is an alternative method based on pattern matching:

```
SeedRandom[1]
set = RandomInteger[100, 5]

Cases[Permutations[set, {3}], {___, x_, ___, y_, ___, z_, ___} /; x > y > z]
```

Here is the `set`:

> {80, 14, 0, 67, 3}

And here are the desired permutations:

> { {80, 14, 0}, {80, 14, 3}, {80, 67, 14}, {80, 67, 0}, {80, 67, 3}, {80, 3, 0}, {14, 3, 0}, {67, 14, 0}, {67, 14, 3}, {67, 3, 0} }

This method does not require the original list to be sorted, whereas kguler's does as it is currently written (although of course that would be trivially easy to do). Of course, that is not an issue in the specific case proposed by the OP, since the OP's list is in fact already sorted.

Of course, either method produces the same results:

```
set = Range[5];
Sort@Cases[Permutations[set, {3}], {___, x_, ___, y_, ___, z_, ___} /; x > y > z];
Sort@(Reverse /@ Subsets[set, {3}]);
% == %%

(*Out: True *)
```