# Descending order of Permutations using Select[Tuples[{5, 4, 3, 2, 1}, {3}], OrderedQ]

Tags: combinatorics, sorting, permutation

I was wondering if there is a possible way to still use OrderedQ and get a descending order of permutations:
This is Ascending order:

```
Select[Tuples[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {3}], OrderedQ]
{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3}, {1, 1, 4}, {1, 1, 5}, {1, 2, 2},
{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 4}, {1, 2, 5}, {1, 3, 3}, {1, 3, 4}, {1, 3, 5},
{1, 4, 4}, {1, 4, 5}, {1, 5, 5}, {2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 3}, {2, 2, 4},
{2, 2, 5}, {2, 3, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 5}, {2, 4, 4}, {2, 4, 5},
{2, 5, 5}, {3, 3, 3}, {3, 3, 4}, {3, 3, 5}, {3, 4, 4}, {3, 4, 5},
 {3, 5, 5}, {4, 4, 4}, {4, 4, 5}, {4, 5, 5}, {5, 5, 5}
```

And i need them in Descending order, for eg:

```
{{3,2,1},{3,1,1},{1,1,1}.. etc}
```

Please help me :)

Comment: What if you just replace 1->6, 2->5,3->4,4->3,5->2,6->1?

Comment: Related: [(82522)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/82522/121),
[(83791)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83791/121),
[(83938)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83938/121),
[(84023)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84023/121),
[(84147)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84147/121)

Comment: How about using `Reverse` on your output lists?  Or using `OrderedQ@Reverse@#&` as your test function?

Comment: ... or `Select[Tuples[Reverse@{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {3}], GreaterEqual @@ # &]`

Comment: Ok thanks guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some options:

```
t = Tuples[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {3}];

Reverse /@ Select[t, OrderedQ]

Select[t, OrderedQ] ~Reverse~ 2

Select[t, OrderedQ @* Reverse]

Select[t, Reverse /* OrderedQ]

Select[t, OrderedQ[#, GreaterEqual] &]

6 - Select[t, OrderedQ]
```

Comment: Wow, thanks so much!